# Spring Cloud AWS messaging with a circuit breaker

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, circuit-breaker, spring-cloud-aws, spring-cloud-circuitbreaker

I would like some pointers/guide in how to configure a circuit breaker when working with "Spring Cloud AWS messaging" with an annotation driven approach:

I'm using spring cloud AWS to work with an SQS and I wan't to use the "SqsListener" (https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.4.2/reference/html/index.html#receiving-a-message).
After receiving a message I will make some down stream calls and after they complete I will delete the message. In case the downstream calls fails I would like to impl. a circuit breaker (with some backoff mechanism).

I prefer to use the "Annotation-driven listener" but I don't see how can I configure a circuit breaker (preferably the spring cloud circuit breaker but any other will do as well https://spring.io/guides/gs/cloud-circuit-breaker/).

IIUC I could use the other approach of "Receiving a message" (https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.4.2/reference/html/index.html#receiving-a-message) to consume messages and apply the circuit breaker there (although I would prefer to avoid it) - is that correct? Does anyone have experience doing that?

Comment: Did you find anything for this ?

Comment: unfortunately not yet